# Why does the @EncodeURL appear not to work?

Tags: xpages

I have simple page that I'm using to try and test the @EncodeUrl function from the Extension Library :

```
<xp:panel id="encodeurl">

    <xp:inputText value="#{viewScope.encodeurl}" />
    <xp:br />
    <xp:text value="#{javascript:var x =  @EncodeUrl(viewScope.encodeurl);  print( x );  return x; }"
        escape="true" />
    <xp:button value="submit" id="button1">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
            refreshMode="partial" refreshId="encodeurl">
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>

</xp:panel>
```

Using the form to encode

> http://127.0.0.2/BlogTesting.nsf/ExtLibURLFormulas.xsp?my_Parameter=spaces and $ymbol$

doesn't encode do as I would expect [as exampled elsewhere](https://xcellerant.net/2014/09/04/url-functions-in-the-extension-library/), i.e :

> http://127.0.0.2/BlogTesting.nsf/ExtLibURLFormulas.xsp?my_Parameter=spaces+and+%24ymbol%24

Rather,  all I get is the same string back, both at the console and the screen. I've tried this on both a stock 9.0 installation,  and  9.0.1FP7 with v17 of the extension library.

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[@EncodeUrl](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.ui.doc/extlib_atfunctions_encodeurl.html) works different than you expect. It

> Adds any necessary attributes to a Domino® URL, such as a session
>   identifier or parameters.

Use

```
java.net.URLEncoder.encode("your string to encode", "utf-8")
```

instead. It encodes the spaces and special characters in URL.
Encode only the parameters, not the entire URL. Also, don't encode parameter separator character `&` nor the parameter name-value separator character `=`.

Comment: Thanks Knut, do you have an example of the output or where the function should be used  ? I'm trying to revise for the Domino 9 application developers upgrade exam

Comment: I've never used @EncodeUrl. So, unfortunately, I don't have a good example. This function isn't mentioned once in all three XPages books either...